# Turn a 2-column table into multiple columns based on row value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a 2-column table with rows as such:

```
1 Brand1
1 Brand2
2 Brand3
2 Brand4
2 Brand2
2 Brand5
3 Brand5
3 Brand2
4 Brand3
```

I would like to turn each value from the 1st column into a column header and below have the list of values from the 2nd column:

```
1        2        3        4
Brand1   Brand3   ...      ...
Brand2   Brand4   ...
         Brand2
         Brand5
```

I can't do it through a pivot table, as it must have a numeric value to compute (sum, count, ...) and I haven't found any help, as actually it is quite difficult to explain and to look after a solution in Google (choosing the right terms).

I know there are solutions (in VBA) to do the opposite, but did not manage to find a solution to my problem.

I have seen some specific terms such as "fold" or "unfold" but I'm not sure which one is right nor if it is appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, you'll have to update the code below based upon the number of rows you're using. in the example below, I've used 10.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim numberOfRows As Integer
    numberOfRows = 10 ' UPDATE THIS FOR YOUR NUMBER OF ROWS

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim previousValue As String
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    currentColumn = 97
    For rowNumber = 1 To numberOfRows
        Dim currentValueOfA As String
        Dim currentValueOfB As String
        currentValueOfA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rowNumber).Value
        currentValueOfB = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowNumber).Value

        If (previousValue = "") Then
            previousValue = currentValueOfA
        End If

        If (previousValue = currentValueOfA) Then

            If (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr$(currentColumn) & "1").Value = "") Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr$(currentColumn) & "1").Value = currentValueOfA
            End If

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr$(currentColumn) & i + 1).Value = currentValueOfB

        Else
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
            previousValue = currentValueOfA
            i = 1

            If (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr$(currentColumn) & "1").Value = "") Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr$(currentColumn) & "1").Value = currentValueOfA
            End If

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr$(currentColumn) & i + 1).Value = currentValueOfB
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

This is my Sheet1

[image]

And this is how it looks on Sheet2

[image]

There may be some faults with this (depending on how many rows you have) but based upon the example you gave, it works great.

Comment: I guess I cannot do it without VBA ... thanks for the code!